# Xamarin Forms Change Toolbar Background Color

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mobile, xamarin.android

How can I change the background color of a toolbar taking into consideration that the page is not a **NavigationPage**. I searched but every answer I found requires a navigation page. Thanks in advance.

Comment: how are you displaying a toolbar without a NavigationPage?  Please post the relevant code/XAML

Comment: I am displaying a shell page. I want to change the background color of the bar that contains the flyout menu. t is considered also as a toolbar or am I wrong?